# A Matrix Manipulation Question

Tags: matrices

Let $$ \def\I{\mathop{I}\nolimits} C'= \begin{bmatrix} \I_{N-1} & \I_{N-1} & 0_{(N-1) \times 1}\end{bmatrix} \in \def\M{\mathop{\rm Mat}\nolimits}\M_{N-1, 2N-1} $$ and
$$ B'= \begin{bmatrix} -\I_{N-1} ~~~ 0_{(N-1) \times 1} \\I_N \end{bmatrix} \in \M_{2N-1, N} $$ where $I_K$ is a $K$ by $K$ identity matrix. I am trying to prove the following result where $W$ can be any $(2N-1) \times (2N-1)$ matrix. Any ideas or proof is appreciated. Something that might be useful is $BC=0$ and $B'(BB')^{-1}B$ is not equal to identity matrix.

$$[\I_{2N-1}-C(C'WC)^{-1}C'W]B'(BB')^{-1}B=\I_{2N-1}-C(C'WC)^{-1}C'W$$